# Saxon + Spring - IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Attribute http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage

Tags: java, spring, xpath, saxon

I'm trying to move from Xalan to Saxon (for the xslt 2.0 support) and am encountering the following exception.  I've made sure all Xalan jars are no longer in the environment and am now including some of the Saxon 9.1.0.8 jars.

The transformations seem to be working, but this exception is occurring on startup and I'd like to get it resolved.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/app-config-tomcat.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [net.sf.saxon.dom.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@9c8a67] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:903)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1282)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:807)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:579)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [net.sf.saxon.dom.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@9c8a67] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown attribute http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage
        at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.setConfigurationProperty(Configuration.java:3347)
        at net.sf.saxon.dom.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:49)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:99)
        ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Question answered](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/forums/forum/94027/topic/4987137) on the saxon-help list.

Here is a copy for reference should the post become unavailable in the future:

> It looks as if Spring (or an application using Spring) is using the
>   JAXP mechanism to find a DOM implementation, and for some reason is
>   finding the Saxon DOM implementation. This isn't a good idea, because
>   Saxon's DOM implementation isn't a general-purpose one, and there are
>   lots of things it doesn't support, for example update. So why is it
>   finding it? Saxon doesn't register this implementation in the JAR file
>   manifest, so I don't think it's finding it simply from the classpath
>   search; that would suggest someone is setting the relevant system
>   property. Setting the system property jaxp.debug="1" might shed more
>   light as to why this DocumentBuilder is being loaded.
>
> It's possible that the problem is benign in that the DocumentBuilder
>   is being loaded but isn't being used, or properties are being set on
>   it that aren't actually needed; or perhaps Spring catches the
>   exception and recovers by loading a different DocumentBuilder. But I
>   agree with you, it would be better to stop it happening.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: Sorry, but if people ask the same question on two forums, I'm not prepared to answer it twice. That rewards bad practice.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we also consider it bad practice to provide link only answers therefore I have quoted your answer from the mailing list.